# Как удалить iframe из кода JS внутри фрейма

Tags: javascript, iframe

У меня есть `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="include_modal/index.html" id="qwiz" allowtransparency="true">
```

внутри него есть есть событие "Закрыть", я хочу сделать что то типа такого из самого iframe'a:

```
$(".close").click( function(){
    $('#qwiz').css('opacity', '0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы просто хотите сделать ваш `iframe` невидимым по нажатию на кнопку то:

```
$(".close-button").on("click", function () {
    $("#qwiz").css("opacity", "0")
})
```

Что бы "закрыть" блок:

```
// замените $("#qwiz").css("opacity", "0") на    
$("#qwiz").hide()
```

Что бы удалить блок из DOM:

```
// замените $("#qwiz").css("opacity", "0") на    
$("#qwiz").remove()
```

Comment: Да но только я хочу это сделать внутри фрейма, смотрите есть Родитель и есть Frame, внутри фреймя я должен нажать на кнопку, а на родителе добавить правило чтоб скрыть элемент, тоесть мне нужно выполнить код JS который в ифрейме, но выполнить на родителе.